# what is the best collection type to return in an API

Tags: c#, collections

i have always thought that returning Arrays were better than lists when having a public API but it seems now there are all these functions on lists that are available through LINQ, etc.

Has the best practice changed here for returning collections of primitives or objects?

for example:

```
Order[] GetOrders();
List<Order> GetOrders();
IEnumerable<Order> GetOrders();
IQueryable<Order> Get Orders();
```

Comment: Note that all of the above types support Linq to varying degrees, either through `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the most commonly used type is `IEnumerable<T>`

- With a `IEnumerable<T>` return type you can use the `yield` keyword and this enables delayed enumeration and execution of your method. (A common complaint for example is that the System.IO.Path.GetFiles() does NOT return a `IEnumerable<T>` but returns an Array which means that when you call the method all items need to be enumerated regardless if you need them or not. - You have the same disadvantage with `List<T>`)
- Most LINQ extension methods work on an `IEnumerable<T>`
- The `IEnumerable<T>` return type doesn't assume anything specific about the caller. If the caller needs a list or array they can always create one.
- `IEnumerable<T>` is implemented by `List<T>` and `Array` and it is therefore easy to change the implementation of your method and still support the previous return type.

Comment: Just make sure you don't allow someone to cast your `IEnumerable<T>` to, for example, a `List<T>` and change it if that would break an invariant of the class.  See my answer for more details.

Comment: After many years returning `IEnumerable<T>` I'm now wondering whether this advertises to callers that what I've returned isn't yet materialized, or at least leaves the caller in doubt about whether or not to call `ToList / ToArray`.

Answer (score 7):

As I generally only return immutable (unmodifiable) objects from properties/methods, this answer assumes you want to do the same.

Don't forget about `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` which returns an immutable collection that can still be accessed by index.

If you're using `IEnumerable<T>` and releasing your type into the uncontrollable wilderness, be wary of this:

```
class MyClass {
    private List<int> _list;
    public IEnumerable<int> Numbers {
        get { return _list; }
    }
}
```

As a user could do this and mess up the internal state of your class:

```
var list = (List<int>)myClass.Numbers;
list.Add(123);
```

This would violate the read-only intention for the property.  In such cases, your getter should look like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<int> Numbers {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(_list); }
    }
```

Alternatively you could call `_list.ToReadOnly()`. I wrote it out in full to show the type.

That will stop anyone modifying your state (unless they use reflection, but that's really hard to stop unless you build immutable collections like those use in many functional programming languages, and that's a whole other story).

If you're returning read only collections, you're better off declaring the member as `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` as then certain actions perform faster (getting count, accessing items by index, copying to another collection).

Personally I'd like to see the framework include and use an interface like this:

```
public interface IReadOnlyCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    T this[int index] { get; }
    int Count { get; }
    bool Contains(T item);
    void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex);
    int IndexOf(T item);
}
```

You can get all these functions using extension methods on top of `IEnumerable<T>` but they're not as performant.

Answer (score 6):

Do you want the collection to be immutable? `IEnumerable<T>`
Mutable? `IList<T>`

Do you need indexes? `IList<T>`

With a list or array, the API consumer has full capability to add, remove, delete, clear, etc.

With an `IEnumerable<T>`, the API consumer gets a "bag" of items, with no particular order, no index, and no methods to modify the collection.

There are some limited circumstances in which you might want to return an `IQueryable<T>`, but they are often specific to building queries piecemeal.

In general, I'd default to `IEnumerable<T>`. I might use a `List<T>` as a backing field, but only want to allow the user to `Add()`, for example -- not to remove, clear, or anything else, so I declare a `public void Add<T>(T item)` that just adds the item to the backing field list.

Comment: Don't forget about ICollection<T> if you don't need indexes. IList<T> implements ICollection<T> and just adds an indexer, IndexOf(T item), Insert(int index, T item) and RemoveAt(int index).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what the others have said I want to add that you should never return `IQueryable` unless you're retrieving the objects from some remote datasource. `IQueryable` is a *query object* that will fetch the results on behalf of the caller. When using LINQ, an `IQueryable` will usually take an expression tree that will be translated for use by some other system (e.g. SQL Server).

See http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2008/12/01/returning-iqueryable-lt-t-gt.aspx for more details.